# Compile PHP with intl

Tags: php, compilation, icu, intl

I want to compile php with intl extention.

I am compiling with --enabled-intl.

It gives me error that icu required.
So i have install icu using yum install icu libicu-devel

Now I am getting the following error:

> checking for ICU 3.4 or greater... found 51.2
>   checking for c++... c++
>   checking whether the C++ compiler (c++  -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib) works... configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C++ compiler cannot create executables.

Here is the content of my config.log

> configure:52751: c++ -o conftest  -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib conftest.C -ls    qlite3 -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl  -lrt -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -ldl -lxml2 -lz -liconv     -lm -ldl -ldl -lm -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -ldl -lm -licuio 1>&5
>   /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to `gzopen64@ZLIB_1.2.3.3'
>   /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so: undefined reference to`gzdirect@ZLIB_1.2.2.3'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   configure: failed program was:

Comment: Have you tried a full update of the box before ? "yum update" . Be sure also to have "yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake"

Comment: Yes all are installed.

Comment: From the log it seems you have a zlib and libxml problem too, is it well installed too ? "yum install zlib zlib-devel libxml libxml-devel" ?

Comment: Yes all are installed

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that supposed to be --enable-intl (with no 'd' in enable)?

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it by going to

http://www.xmlsoft.org/intro.html

Download and compile it manually.